# How to properly avoid JOINs to count associated elements in Django?

Tags: django, caching, orm

In a "many to one" relationship, is it a good Django practice to store the count of related elements on the "one" side, or Django had a better mechanism reducing the overhead ? 
Say we have two tables : "Posts" and "Likes" and we can have several likes on one post. My DBA instinct is to add a nb_likes field on "Posts" and increment it in the Like(post_id,user_id...) method. The default Django ORM behavior is to make a "JOIN" which seems to be very wasteful.

Comment: No. i dont think so. Thats why it built. No need to fetch all data of relations.You can explicitly call `count`

Comment: "My DBA instinct is to add a nb_likes field on "Posts" and increment it in the Like(post_id,user_id...) method." => strange enough, most DBAs I know would only consider this kind of denormalization as a last resort kludge...

Comment: @bruno In my case the bottleneck is clearly the database so i'm very concerned about performances, even at the price of some "ugliness". I get your point, but this can be implemented via a TRIGGER in order to preserve the integrity of the database. Honestly, i'm in process of evaluating the benefits to move a legacy PHP/Mysql application to Django but i don't have a good measure about the performance cost associated with moving from optimized SQL queries to ORM.

Comment: @Humphrey Django's ORM can by itself do some smart things if you learn to use it properly (ie using `values` or `values_list` querysets, `prefetch_related`, annotations, aggregations etc), but if you need complex queries or more manual "optimizations" nothing prevents you from bypassing the ORM here and there and doing raw SQL queries instead.

Comment: And it's actually not a Django problem - if the problem is with a `JOIN` being to costly performance wise for your use case you'll have the exact same problem whatever the language / framework used (and the solution will very probably be the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know where you got the idea that "The default Django ORM behavior is to make a "JOIN".

I have `Blog` and `Article` as models with `Article` having a foreign key on `Blog`. I selected one blog at random and ran:

```
blog.article_set.count()
```

Then inspected the generated SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `__count` FROM `core_article` WHERE `article`.`blog_id` = 10'
```

So obviously no `JOIN` here.

EDIT : you added in your comment that

> but my concern was about pages showing a list of posts with their respective vote count (or in your example a page showing say a table listing 20 Blogs with the number of contained Articles for each of them)

And indeed in this case ie:

```
Blog.objects.annotate(nb_arts=Count('article_set'))
```

you will get a join in the query, quite obviously - but that's how you'd write the query anyway if you stick to a normalized schema, so I don't see how it relates to Django's ORM.

So to make a long story short: whatever the language and/or framework, for your use case, you either stick to a normalized schema and need a JOIN or don't want to pay / can't afford the cost of the JOIN and have to denormalize. Whether it's a "good practice" or not is another question, but that has nothing to do with Django or whatever language / framework you are using.

Comment: Yes, you are right in this case, but my concern was about pages showing a list of posts with their respective vote count (or in your example a page showing say a table listing 20 Blogs with the number of contained Articles for each of them).

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes the problem is related to ORMs in general. Il was hoping that there was some smart caching mechanism avoiding the JOIN in these situations.

Comment: I found that Sqlalchemy was providing such thing : http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aggregates.html. Anything similar in Django ?

Comment: Not out of the box but AFAICT this can very probably be implemented using signals and/or overrides. This being said when I read " uses single query per transaction" I'm not sure this will save you that much for the example use case - by default a transaction is tied to a request/response cycle, so it looks like you'd  still need quite a few queries for a single "display a list of posts with likes count" request (but I may not have fully understood how sql_alchemy implemented this feature - I just had a quick glance at the doc).

Comment: FWIW if going the denormalization way you can easily use signals to automagically update the stored likes count when a like is created or deleted.